# How to Place html controls dynamically in to a div with x,y positions without using absolute as position

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

How do you place HTML controls dynamically into a div with x,y positions, without using absolute as position?

I am generating HTML controls dynamically in ASP.NET with x, y positions having absolute position. I have two files where I put two different div's, I fill the div's content with the generated one, but because of absolute position it places the control taking page as relative to that, but not the div.

I want the exact positions inside the div it self rather than page.

For example if I got top as 20px and left as 40px with absolute, the control should start from the same position inside div, but it places the control with page.

Please help me to place the control inside the div itself with x,y positions without using absolute position.

Comment: Post some code here. Please help us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

To place an element by specifying `left` and `top` pixel distances you must use `absolute` positioning. However, it sounds like you want this position to be relative to the containing element, not the body of the document. If that is the case, make the containing element `position: relative`.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/um9Vu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Rory's got you covered, but in the event that you don't want the controls to not be taken out of the layout, you might try using `margin-left` and `margin-top`.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJaTa/)